# 401.13 Error within cfdiv or div with ColdFusion 11

Tags: html, iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Asking to see if anyone within a CAC enabled server environment has encountered and issue with repeatedly getting a 403.13 Forbidden error within a DIV or CFDIV element.

We upgraded our ColdFusion server to ColdFusion 11 and our users seem to be getting this error much more.

Comment: By CAC, you mean Common Access Card ?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with any HTML elements. It is a client certificate issue or Certificate Revocation List server issue. [Error message: HTTP 403.13 Forbidden: client certificate revoked](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/248058/error-message-http-403.13-forbidden-client-certificate-revoked)

Comment: Correct ah7866.

That's what I'm telling my IT people but they insist its my code.

Comment: I believe we've run into this error recently on a SharePoint system that is connecting across another secured network through the CAC's Single Sign On. If I remember correctly, this is a Kerberos error - as in it wasn't usable across the type of trusted connection we have. It's not necessarily code, and there may not be much that can be done about it. If it's CAC-enforced, you probably don't have a lot of control over the network topology that's underneath this. I'll try to get more information about the issue, but I know we've been working on it for weeks.

Comment: Shawn, that would be AWESOME, thanks!